# Create a hierarchical index from a .tsv file (pandas)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a data frame of this shape (not the actual one):

Fruit Banana House-1 15

Fruit Banana House-2 4

Fruit Apple House-2 6

Fruit Apple House-2 8

Vegetable Broccoli House-3 8

Vegetable Lettuce House-4 12

Vegetable Peppers House-5 3

Vegetable Corn House-4 4

Seasoning Olive Oil House-6 2

Seasoning Vinegar House-7 2

I'd like to know if there is a way to create in Pandas a Data Frame with a hierarchical index with these two levels: type of food, food. And then assign to each a location and an amount. I can't do this manually because the actual dataset has over 60,000 rows. A way that I thought of was creating a list from the tsv file and then using it as the index, but I imagine there is a more automatic way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
        Type       Food      Loc  Num
0      Fruit     Banana  House-1   15
1      Fruit     Banana  House-2    4
2      Fruit      Apple  House-2    6
3      Fruit      Apple  House-2    8
4  Vegetable   Broccoli  House-3    8
5  Vegetable    Lettuce  House-4   12
6  Vegetable    Peppers  House-5    3
7  Vegetable       Corn  House-4    4
8  Seasoning  Olive Oil  House-6    2
9  Seasoning    Vinegar  House-7    2

In [13]: df = df.set_index(['Type','Food'])

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                         Loc  Num
Type      Food
Fruit     Banana     House-1   15
          Banana     House-2    4
          Apple      House-2    6
          Apple      House-2    8
Vegetable Broccoli   House-3    8
          Lettuce    House-4   12
          Peppers    House-5    3
          Corn       House-4    4
Seasoning Olive Oil  House-6    2
          Vinegar    House-7    2
```

BTW you can do it "on-the-fly" when reading your TSV/CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=None,
                 columns=['Type','Food','Loc','Num'],
                 index_col=['Type','Food'])
```